# Do you run a conduit under or over concrete wrap in the basement?

Tags: insulation, basement, conduit

My basement concrete wall is covered with a concrete wrap and is anchored to the wall. The walls are unfinished.

If you want to add an outlet down the wall to a workbench, do you run the conduit under or over the wrap?

Comment: What is a concrete wrap, exactly? A photo would help illuminate options.

Answer (score 1):

On the inside--you don't want to mess with the wrap. By inside I mean close to your bench, not under the wrap. I thought I should expand under the wrap is a usually damp area that is somewhat corrosive I think of EMT for basements but messing with this barrier is not a good idea.

Comment: He is right, you don't want to do anything to that barrier, it is there for moisture protection. You can surface mount the conduit over it, or you can use surface mount wire duct (formerly called "Wiremold") into a receptacle box.